# Channel impulse response in freqency domain

Tags: digital-communications

I have a doubt about DFT matrix and channel impulse response.

Let $h$ is a channel impulse response , $F$ is a DFT matrix. IF I take a product. I got: 
$$ F* h=\tilde{h}$$

$\tilde{h}$ is a frequency response of the channel, isn't? or channel impulse response in frequnce domain

Comment: If $h$ in time-domain, taking Fourier Transform will give its frequency response.

Comment: $\tilde{h}$ is the frequency response of the channel. How could frequency response of the channel and channel impulse response in frequency domain be different? ;-)

Comment: @jomegaA I have read a research paper where h was called as channel impulse response and product DFT matrix with `h` as channel coefficient in freq domain. " coefficient in freq domain" made me a question

Comment: ...perhaps the channel impulse response and channel coefficients mean the same. Yes, the product of DFT matrix and in your case $F$ with $h$ is channel impulse response in frequency domain.

Comment: As in the answer given by Engineer you may understand what is the product of `dftmtx` and `h` is. Or you can take `fft(h)` which is also the channel impulse response in frequency domain.

Answer (score 3):

You are right. If you have MATLAB, you can do a little experiment to double check yourself:

```
h = randn(100, 1);     % make some random impulse response
F = dftmtx(length(h)); % make the DFT matrix (100-by-100)
abs(fft(h) - F*h)      % this number should be small
```

Comment: Want to put an additional info here, `F*h` is actually the Fourier transform of `h` (frequency response). $\\$ From matlab documentation, "A discrete Fourier transform matrix is a complex matrix whose matrix product with a vector computes the discrete Fourier transform of the vector. dftmtx takes the FFT of the identity matrix to generate the transform matrix."

Comment: Nevertheless the faster approach could be `fft(h)`

Comment: if a frequency response is given, can I take ifft to get a channel matrix?

Comment: If $\mathbf{h}$ is instead a channel matrix $\mathbf{H}$, you can still do $\mathbf{F}\mathbf{H}=\tilde{\mathbf{H}}$ to get the DFT of $\mathbf{H}$. You just need to make sure that the number of rows in $\mathbf{H}$ is the same as the $\mathbf{F}$